# Disable image upload in Summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, summernote

Is there any way to completely disable uploading of images in Summernote, but keep the image url input? The closest thing I found was the `disableDragAndDrop: true` option, but this doesn't remove the upload button from the image pop-up

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There's probably a better way to accomplish what you're going for... but a very simple solution that comes to mind is to just add this to your stylesheets:

```
.note-group-select-from-files {
  display: none;
}
```

It works perfectly to leave just the image url input, and accomplishes what you're going for unless someone were to inspect element and discover that the upload element still exists with display none:

[image]

---

Edit :
I took a look at the Summernote source code, and it looks like the above solution is actually a good way to go. There's currently no api to disable just the file upload button, let alone do so while leaving the img url input intact. You could always add it and open a pull request, of course.

https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/4b1bf144862a88899a464ddfab6bc0593a061fbc/src/js/bs3/module/ImageDialog.js#L24

```
  var body = '<div class="form-group note-group-select-from-files">' +
               '<label>' + lang.image.selectFromFiles + '</label>' +
               '<input class="note-image-input form-control" type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />' +
               imageLimitation +
             '</div>' +
             '<div class="form-group" style="overflow:auto;">' +
               '<label>' + lang.image.url + '</label>' +
               '<input class="note-image-url form-control col-md-12" type="text" />' +
             '</div>';
```

Answer (score 21):

You can override the toolbar and define your own set of buttons there. Here is a sample codesnippet:

```
$("#summernote").summernote({
        height: 300,
        toolbar: [
            [ 'style', [ 'style' ] ],
            [ 'font', [ 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear'] ],
            [ 'fontname', [ 'fontname' ] ],
            [ 'fontsize', [ 'fontsize' ] ],
            [ 'color', [ 'color' ] ],
            [ 'para', [ 'ol', 'ul', 'paragraph', 'height' ] ],
            [ 'table', [ 'table' ] ],
            [ 'insert', [ 'link'] ],
            [ 'view', [ 'undo', 'redo', 'fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help' ] ]
        ]
    });
```

This code generates the toolbar without video and image insert option and with all other options available. You can check the detail API documentation [here](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#basic-api).

Comment: he / she just want to disable upload from pc not from URL so if we use your solution it will delete image feature completely.

Answer (score 2):

Find this code in summernote.js

```
tplDialog = function (lang, options) {
      var tplImageDialog = function () {
        return '<div class="note-image-dialog modal" aria-hidden="false">' +
                 '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                   '<div class="modal-content">' +
                     '<div class="modal-header">' +
                       '<button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">&times;</button>' +
                       '<h4>' + lang.image.insert + '</h4>' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div class="modal-body">' +
                       '<div class="row-fluid">' +
                         '<h5>' + lang.image.selectFromFiles + '</h5>' +
                         '<input class="note-image-input" type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" />' +
                         '<h5>' + lang.image.url + '</h5>' +
                         '<input class="note-image-url form-control span12" type="text" />' +
                       '</div>' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                       '<button href="#" class="btn btn-primary note-image-btn disabled" disabled="disabled">' + lang.image.insert + '</button>' +
                     '</div>' +
                   '</div>' +
                 '</div>' +
               '</div>';
      };
```

Remove this code :

```
'<h5>' + lang.image.selectFromFiles + '</h5>' +
'<input class="note-image-input" type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" />' +
```

Now file upload input is remove from modal dialog.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Jquery**
This worked for me

```
 $('div.note-group-select-from-files').remove();
```

Or if (as suggested by dwilda) you want to check that the element exists before attempting to remove it:

```
var imageUploadDiv = $('div.note-group-select-from-files');
if (imageUploadDiv.length) {
  imageUploadDiv.remove();
}
```

Comment: CSS would be better approach since we don't know when the tag is going to be present in DOM. The may be nothing to remove()

Comment: That's true dwilda. I just thought someone never can tell could inspect element and reverse hidden to visible.

Comment: A side note: there's no need for the second code snippet. If the jquery selector delivers an empty result set, you can still call `remove()` on this empty set. No exception will be thrown

Comment: I like this approach since hiding the simply layer via css leaves the file input in my post array. If it's not a field I want in my form, I'd rather have it removed vs simply hidden ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it seems to be complicated but you can simply redeclare the toolbar:

```
    `$('#summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']]
  ]
});`
```

Comment: The question was how to keep the ability to add an image by URL, but remove the ability to upload an image. This removes both, so it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

For summernote version `.8*`

Use the following to remove the button:

```
.note-insert {
    display: none
}
```

Users will still be able to drag and drop pictures.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit of code i found by removing this code in summernote.js will remove that UPLOAD FEATURE

Just remove this form your file as any of above answers won't work for me

```
'<div class="form-group note-form-group note-group-select-from-files">' +
               '<label class="note-form-label">' + lang.image.selectFromFiles + '</label>' +
               '<input class="note-image-input form-control note-form-control note-input" '+
               ' type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />' +
               imageLimitation +
             '</div>' +
```

Comment: It's not usually advisable to edit other people's libraries, unless you want to be on the hook for maintenance after each update.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.note-group-select-from-files').first().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Disable image button

.note-insert.btn-group>.btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
    display:none;
}

//Disable Video button

.note-insert.btn-group>.btn:last-child:not(:first-child), .btn-group>.dropdown-toggle:not(:first-child) {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).